# How to request for login in adminMongo before accessing database

Tags: database, mongodb, authentication, admin, createuser

This is what exactly I am talking about, I first want my other users to log in then access database to process further

[image]

Comment: please add some more detail in your question.

Comment: I am accessing my local DB  and to have UI FOR my database I am using adminMongo an open source interface now what I want, set up authentication before accessing DB @SaurabhMistry

Comment: why are you using adminMongo ? is that any requirements ?  you can use MongoDBCompass ...to find , view , edit , delete records

Comment: for large scales like if my colleges want to access DB TO PROCESS THEIR OWN REQUEST SO INSTEAD OF COMMAND LINE THEY CNA DIRECTLY TYPE COMMANDS OR PROCESS MongoDB QUERY

Comment: can i create user in MongoDBCompass

Comment: yes you can insert record by key value, https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass

Comment: you can also try RoboMongo : https://robomongo.org/

Comment: yeah i am getting you.. will i be able to login before doing any processing are you getting me login interface before accessign db ?